# Django. How to set default option use generic CreateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Model:

```
class MyModel(model.Models)
   status = models.ForeignKey(Statuses, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
```

Views:

```
class MyViewCreate(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyFrom
    template_name = 'mymodel_form.html'
```

Forms:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

How i can in form set default or first value on the option list >

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `initial` like this:

```
class MyViewCreate(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyFrom
    initial = {'status': '0'}
    template_name = 'mymodel_form.html'
```

or like this:

```
class MyViewCreate(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyFrom
    template_name = 'mymodel_form.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        state = get_object_or_404(MyModel, some_field=some_value)
        return {
            'state':state,
        }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Which are these _some_field=some_value_ ?

Comment: prefect thanks , some of people know that , thank you